# Please confirm function of i % 2 == 0

Tags: java

My understanding of this equation is:

Any even number that is divided by 2 will not have any fractional component in the answer.

```
       4 / 2 = 2
```

Any odd number that is divided by 2 will have a fractional will have a fractional component in the answer.

```
       3 / 2 = 1.5
```

The equation i % == 0 evaluates for a fractional component. Thus a fractional component means that it is an odd number.

```
        3 % 2 == 0 
        1.5 != 0
```

Do I have that right?

Comment: Checking whether the modulus operation yields 0 is actually the correct way to distinguish even and odd numbers since it works for negative numbers too: -3 % 2 yields -1, which does not equal 0, so -3 is odd. -4 % 2 yields 0, so even number.

Comment: It checks a number is even.

Answer (score 2):

> Any even number that is divided by 2 will not have any **fractional
>   component**

NO, it doesn't check for fractional component rather it checks for *Remainder*. So modulus operator `%` gives back remainder of the operation and yes if it's a even number then dividing it by 2 will leave a `0` as remainder.

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder of the number on the left divided by the number on the right.

```
3 % 2 == 1; // true
4 % 2 == 0; // true
```

So, if you take a number and perform `% 2` on it, if the result is 0 then the number is even. If the result is 1 then the number is odd.

```
boolean isEven(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` as an operator represents modulus/mod/remainder operation. So if a number is divided by n then possible values for remainder `r` is: `0 <= r < n` with that said,

if a number is divided by 2 then it can lead to 0 or 1 as remainder. if it results in 0 then the number was even and if it results in 1 then number was odd.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You have all been a great help. I am a returning adult learner and it's been a while since I have had basic math. Had completely forgotten about remainders. You are all awesome! Thanks for taking the time to reply.